# Previous declaration of ___ was here?

Tags: c, list

```
void delete_node(node_t *p, void *item) {

    while(p -> next != NULL && (p->next)-> item != item) {
        p = p -> next;
    }

    if (p -> next == NULL) {
        printf ("The element you are searching for is not in the list\n");  
    }

    node_t *temp;
    temp = p -> next;
    p -> next = temp -> next;
    temp -> prev = p;
    free(temp);
}
```

I have this code in a .c file.

```
void delete_node(node_t *p, void *item);
```

This prototype is in a .h file and I get an error that says "conflicting types for delete_node" and "previous declaration of delete_node was here" and I do not know why.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

This is my node_t struct:

```
typedef struct node {
    void *item;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node_t;
```

Comment: What does the prototype look like?

Comment: How/where do you define `node_t`?

Comment: It's what I posted below the first chunk of code

Comment: If those are _exactly_ the uses of `delete_node`, and the compiler is complaining that `delete_node` was declared before in the header file, the only explanation I can think of is that somehow the type `node_t` isn't the same at both points. But that doesn't sound right either... Please show the _complete_ header file(s) and code file(s), preferably after cutting out everything that isn't relevant (while keeping the error message, and not getting new ones).

Comment: This is only part of my code, node_t is defined in a struct @mcl

Comment: Is node_t defined in the same header file as `delete_node`?

Comment: Yea they are both defined in the .h file

Comment: Could you come up with an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) and post that?

Comment: what is the code at `___` (the line number and the file on the error).

Comment: When I compile the code you have here, plus a useless main I get no error or warning. It might help if you post the smallest possible .c and .h files that exhibit the problem, as well as the compile command you're using.

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix the error. All I had to do was recompile without an output and then again with an output

Comment: Identifiers which end with `_t` are reserved by the language. Don't create them.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a definition the most likely cause of this error is that you used `delete_node` before the compiler encountered the declaration or definition.  If that's the case `delete_node` will be assumed to have a return type of `int` at that point.  Hence when the compiler later sees the actual definition / declaration of `delete_node` it will produce that error.

Search for uses of `delete_node` and make sure that the definition of `delete_node` is always processed before the usage.  Ideally this should be included at the top of the `.c` file or in a header file if `delete_node` is used in multiple `.h` files

Comment: @user2041197 that error will only trigger if there is a previous definition or previous usage